# Section of universal curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces

Let $\mathcal{M}_{g,1}\to \mathcal{M}_g$ be the universal genus $g$ curve, let $K_g$ denote the funciton field of $\mathcal{M}_g$. Take the generic fiber $C\to \mathrm{Spec}{(K_g)}$, after some finite extension $L/K_g$, $C_L$ will admit a rational point. Is there a good choice for $L$? If there is, do we know $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K_g)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me assume $g>2$, so that there is a curve $C$ over $K_g$ of genus $g$ (the *generic curve*) -- the genus condition assures that the generic curve has no automorphisms.  It is known but not obvious that $C$ has no $K_g$-rational points (this is due to Hain-Matsumoto in characteristic zero and Watanabe in positive characterstic, if I remember correctly).  If you choose any closed point of $C$ with residue field $L$, the base change to $L$ will have a rational point.

There is a reasonably canonical choice of $L$.  Namely, let $W_g$ be the moduli space of curves with a Weierstrass point.  Then $W_g$ is connected and $W_g\to M_g$ is not Galois, but it is generically etale with monodromy group is $S_{g(g^2-1)}$ by [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01388708) of Eisenbud-Harris.  Thus letting $L_g$ be the function field of $W_g$, the generic curve obtains a rational point over $L_g$ (namely, the generic Weierstrass point).  $L_g/K_g$ is not Galois, but its Galois closure has Galois group $S_{g(g^2-1)}$.

Of course this works in genus $<2$ as well, as long as you consider the generic point of $\mathcal{M}_g$ to be a stacky point rather than Spec of a field.

Comment: The theorem you attribute to Hain-Matsumoto is due to John Hubbard in his thesis.  Hubbard proves something much stronger: except for $g=2$, there are not even any (meromorphic) sections after pullback to the Teichmueller space (for $g=2$, the six Weierstrass points gives holomorphic sections over the Teichmueller space).  Hain-Matsumoto prove that, even on the level of homotopy (i.e., for some induced mixed Hodge structure on some homotopy group), there is no section of the natural short exact sequence (as there would be if there were a holomorphic section).

Comment: @JasonStarr: Ah great!  I wasn't aware of Hubbard's result.  The statement seems to be pure characteristic zero -- do you know if there are any references in characteristic p predating Watanabe (which is also an anabelian statement)?

Comment: I do not know about Watanabe's result.  Of course the result in positive characteristic does follow from Franchetta's conjecture (proved in characteristic zero by John Harer, extended to positive characteristic by Stefan Schroeer).

Comment: Ah, great, this does indeed predate Watanabe's result.

Answer (score 4):

This got too long to be a comment, but...

Isn't $\mathcal{M}_g$ only a stack? Isn't the function field of a stack just the function field of its coarse moduli scheme (if it exists?)

For example, unlike in the case of schemes, I don't think there's a canonical map $Spec(K_g)\rightarrow\mathcal{M}_g$. Any such map is by definition given by an object of $\mathcal{M}_g$ over $K_g$, which is precisely the pullback of $\mathcal{M}_{g,1}\rightarrow\mathcal{M}_g$ to $K_g$.

For example, if you replace $\mathcal{M}_g$ with $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$, then there are infinitely many elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}(j)$ with $j$-invariant $j$, corresponding to infinitely many maps $Spec\;\mathbb{Q}(j)\rightarrow\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$, each of which can be thought of as a "generic point", and none of them seem to be preferable over any other.

See for example Noam Elkies' answer to: [Questions about the "universal elliptic curve" over the affine $j$-line punctured at 0 and 1728](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187110/questions-about-the-universal-elliptic-curve-over-the-affine-j-line-puncture)

Comment: For $g>2$, the generic curve has no automorphisms.  So (not entirely obviously), $\mathcal{M}_g$ admits an open substack which is a scheme.

Comment: @DanielLitt Ah, nice! I didn't know that. I suppose my "answer" still makes sense for $g = 1,2$ so I'll leave it up for now.